Cell colour formatting
How do I format a cell "O4" to appear red, if cell "N4" has a number in it?
I am trying conditional formatting but cannot find the correct.
I do not understand why I have to have so many characters in my question but this is in here to make up the characters.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
